# Can't get text to speech to work

Tags: swift

I get the following message when I try the code below:

2014-07-28 13:19:14.251 MySingleView[3750:461865] Speech initialization error: 2147483665

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

I'm running this in an iPad 2 simulator on my Mac running Mavericks using Xcode6 - Beta 4.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var voice = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {
        var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:"This is a test")
        voice.speakUtterance(utterance)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an old beta? Your code won't compile for me; I need to specify the parameter name on the AVSpeechUtterance initialiser (i.e. `var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "This is a test")`).

Comment: But yes, I can reproduce this, with beta 4. And I can reproduce it with Objective C as well as Swift. Maybe speech just isn't working in the beta? I just built the Objective C version with Xcode 5 and it built and ran fine in a simulator.

Comment: Ooh. I find it somewhat suspicious that the AVFoundation framework doesn't appear to be in the iOS 8 SDK that ships with the beta. AVKit is there, but not AVFoundation. (It's there in the iOS 7 SDK.)

Comment: @MattGibson you are right, I left out the string parameter name when simplifying my original code for posting here -- I have corrected it. As you can see in the code, I am importing AVFoundation and that didn't produce an error, so I'm surprised when you say the beta doesn't include it.

Comment: Well, you're [not alone](http://openradar.appspot.com/17299966) (check the comments—looks like it might work on a real device.)

Comment: For me also, it does work on the device, not on the simulator. On the sim, I get the same error.

Comment: Seeing this in GM as well.  I have an app in the store that crashes on GM on my device.

Comment: My problem turned out to be unrelated. I was assuming (incorrectly) that the synthesizer.delegate retained the object and it doesn't.  Under iOS7 the object was living long enough to allow the app to work.  Under iOS8 the unretained object is being collected much sooner, causing my problem.  No voice on the sim though as others have reported.

Answer (score 17):

The iOS 8 simulators do not support text-to-speech.  However, the iOS 7 simulators do still support text-to-speech (at least as of Xcode 6.1), so if your app works under iOS 7 you can test it on your desktop.

Comment: Any idea when a simulator for iOS8 be released that supports TTS?

Comment: Working now on iOS8.4

Answer (score 1):

As of XCode 6.0.1 the simulator appears to not work at all with the AVSpeechSynthesizer. If you get an error message like, it is a simulator issue and not a program issue. It should work fine on any compatible iOS device.
Refer this link - https://github.com/brettdidonato/TextToSpeech/blob/master/README.md .
I have the same issue in iOS 8.0 simulator. But works fine in iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Text-to-speech is working with iOS8.4 simulator not the other 8.X simulators.

Answer (score 0):

try this
**Swift3**

```
        import UIKit
        import AVFoundation

        class ViewController: UIViewController, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
            }

            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            }

            @IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {
                var utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string:"This is a test")
                utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
                var voice = AVSpeechSynthesizer()                
                voice.delegate = self 
                voice.speak(utterance)
            }
        }
```